# How to pass JSON request

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, afnetworking

I am new to `AFNetworking` framework. I try to send JSON request to the server to get JSON response, so i tried something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://data.mycity.gov/api/views/INLINE/rows.json?method=index"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/json"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest* req,NSHTTPURLResponse *req2, NSError *error,id mex) {
        NSLog(@"Failed");
        NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);

    }];

    [operation start];
```

So i always find my self into the failure block, with this error description:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 400" UserInfo=0x7b58030 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://data.mycity.gov/api/views/INLINE/rows.json?method=index, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 400}
```

Any ideas? am i missing something?

Comment: Malek, i'm not sure what do you mean by JSON request - this is an HTTP Request, maybe some requested parameters are missing. Do you have a specification for the API you are requesting data from?

Comment: Hello Shai, yep,it's a HTTP request but in order to get JSON response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status Code of 400 means - Bad Request
The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

When I try to go to that URL:
http://data.mycity.gov/api/views/INLINE/rows.json?method=index"
, I get a not found error

Make sure the API you are using is correct, if the web service returns JSON, you should be able to type that URL into your browser and get a JSON response.

Comment: I get he source of the problem, i used to work with `ASIHTTPRequest` and i used: `[request appendPostData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
`  Do you know how to do the same with `AFNetworking` ?

Comment: Can you post the web service request code that you used to use with ASI?  If I can see the whole request call before and after I should be able to help ya figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your server is returning 400, "Bad Request". Check that your URL is correct.

BTW your `stringWithFormat` is redundant. You can replace

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/json"]
```

with

```
@"application/json"
```